# What is diiference between shared library (.so) loading using dlopen() and including the shared library in executable?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, dlopen

What is difference between:

1. Loading an Shared library using dlopen() available in dlfcn.h
2. Including the shared library in Android.mk file while building the executable.

Code example:
Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=     \
    test.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \ libtest

LOCAL_MODULE:= test
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES)

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

---

While executing the above 2 methods, which is the better/more efficient way of implementing?

Answer (score 2):

With `dlopen()`, the linker never works for you. You must manually look up each function, before calling it using `dlsym()`. This makes each call-site of a function from a shared object more complex than just doing a plain call and letting the linker sort it out.

Comment: Can u pls provide an example for function lookup?

Answer (score 2):

With method 2 (linker), the whole program doesn't start, if the library is missing. With method 1 (`dlopen`) you can gracefully handle the error, leaving the program running. `dlopen` is used for some special cases, like loading plug-ins, or starting optional features.